# Android java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, android, string

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                                     long id) {
                TextView clickedView = (TextView) view;
                /* Line 79 */ String selectedRouteName = (String) parentAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String temp = selectedRouteName.substring(0, 2);
```

Error shown is:

```
02-18 01:56:53.676: E/AndroidRuntime(821): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
02-18 01:56:53.676: E/AndroidRuntime(821):  at com.coltonnicotera.londontransitguide.SchedulesActivity$1.onItemClick(SchedulesActivity.java:79)
```

Not sure what is causing this, I found [java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872292/java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-java-util-hashmap-exception) and it seems that I'm doing everything right.

Comment: There is not enough info for us to help. Please provide the code of the adapter.

Comment: Why would you think that you COULD cast a HashMap to a String???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that `parentAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position)` is returning a **HashMap** instance, which you're trying to convert to a string with the line

```
String selectedRouteName = (String) parentAdapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

You should check the content of that **AdaptaverView**.

Answer (score 1):

Please compare the java with real life,  you are trying to convert **DOG** object into **Peacock** object , that is not possible.

And you should use `toString()` method of object class for string conversion.