# I've been trying to display the content of my database however I keep getting this error "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap"

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I keep having this error whenever I try to display the contents of my database. I tried following the other answers in StackOverflow that are related to my problem however it still doesn't work.

My database structure is as follows:

```
class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //View Binding
private lateinit var binding: ActivityProfileBinding

    //ActionBar
    private lateinit var actionBar: ActionBar

    private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog

    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var db: DatabaseReference

    private lateinit var scholarName: EditText
    private lateinit var scholarStatus: EditText

    //for displaying records
    private lateinit var rvData: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter: UserAdapter
    private lateinit var users: ArrayList<User>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        //configure action
        actionBar = supportActionBar!!
        actionBar.title = "Profile"

        //init firebase auth
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        checkUser()

        //handle click, logout
        binding.logoutBtn.setOnClickListener {
            firebaseAuth.signOut()
            checkUser()
        }

        //Initialize controls
        scholarName = findViewById(R.id.txtScholarName)
        scholarStatus = findViewById(R.id.txtQuotaStatus)

        users = ArrayList<User>()
        adapter = UserAdapter(this, this.retrieve())
        rvData = findViewById(R.id.rvData)
        var ll: LinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
        rvData.layoutManager = ll
        rvData.adapter = adapter

    }
public fun retrieve():ArrayList<User>{

    var tempUsers: ArrayList<User> = ArrayList<User>()

    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("***********").getReference("Scholars")

    ref.addValueEventListener(object:ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            snapshot.children.forEach{

                var map = it.value as HashMap<String,String>
                var user:User = User(map.get("scholarName").toString(),
                    map.get("scholarStatus").toString())
                tempUsers.add(user)

            }

        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
    return tempUsers
}
```

Here is my userViewHolder

```
class UserViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
    var scholarName: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.txtScholarName)
    var scholarStatus: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.txtQuotaStatus)
}
```

Here is my UserAdapter class

```
class UserAdapter(): Adapter<UserViewHolder>() {
    lateinit var c: Context
    lateinit var scholars: ArrayList<User>

   constructor(c: Context, scholars: ArrayList<User>) : this() {
        this.c = c
        this.scholars = scholars
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
        var v: View = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.usercard,
                 parent, false)

        return UserViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.scholarName.setText(scholars.get(position).scholarName.toString())
        holder.scholarStatus.setText(scholars.get(position).scholarStatus.toString())
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return scholars.size
    }
}
```

Here is my User class

```
class User {
    var scholarName: String = ""
    var scholarStatus: String = ""

    constructor(scholarName: String, scholarStatus: String) {
        this.scholarName = scholarName
        this.scholarStatus = scholarStatus
    }

}
```

Here is the error message that I keep on getting

```
2021-10-29 12:05:11.270 17112-17112/com.example.axieapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.axieapplication, PID: 17112
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
```

Comment: You cannot do this: `it.value as HashMap<String,String>`...as `it.value is String` - only `snapshot` could be casted.

Comment: why are you casting HashMap here `var map = it.value as HashMap<String,String>` it.value is String

Comment: check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10872368/15005298

Comment: What do I change? :( can't understand the link that you sent.. sorry I'm very new here

Comment: How about `snapshot as User` (assuming that the field names would match)?

Comment: Tried replacing the snapshot as user but I still got the same error :(

I don't know if this is correct.. please don't judge me sirs

     override fun onDataChange(User: DataSnapshot) {
          User.children.forEach  {

               var map = it.value as HashMap<String,String>
               var user: User = user(map.get("scholarName").toString(),map.get("scholarStatus").toString())